# SharePoint Search 2013 : How to show display template for a specific custom result type?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I am currently working on SharePoint Search customization and I am facing a problem while displaying the item display template for my custom result type.

In my scenario, I have just created a Custom result type named "Test". Added "Test.html" as display template for my custom result type and "Test_HoverPanel.html" for Hover panel in Site Settings-> Master Pages-> Display Templates -> Search folder.
I want to display this "Test.html" display template when the result is a Word Document and matching type of content should be "ContentType" starts with particular keyword.
Please suggest to me how could I achieve this? If I am doing something wrong then let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with some simple troubleshooting.

1. After uploading and updating your Display Template, did SharePoint
   create the Test.js sister file? This is the actual file that will be
   used as the display template.
2. When you create the Result Type rule did you choose the right
   conditions? I would try Results="Documents"  and Content=Microsoft
   Word and add "ContentType starts with any of Test" (or whatever your
   keyword is).
3. Did you assign the right Display template? Select your Test display
   template and ensure that the DT Url is pointing at your Test.js
   file.
4. Finally, did you publish your display template? This is a publishing
   library, so you need to publish the items for users to see them.

Failing all this, start over with a simple template and build up to your final product incrementally. Be methodical and you will find your error. 
http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

Answer (score 0):

also make sure you set the properties for your template file (html) right, target control type should SearchResults, otherwhise it won't show up in the dropdown of the result type